# how insert mysql data in php for sending sms using Buk Sms Api

Tags: php, mysql, api, http

I've created a project where we send SMS to our users with this code:

```
<?php
$USERNAME = urlencode ('username');
$PASSWORD = urlencode ('password');
$TXT = urlencode ('test msg');
$PHONE = '7867564567';
$url = "http://bulksms.com:8080/WebSMS/SMSAPI.jsp?username=$USERNAME&password=$PASSWORD&sendername=ONLINE&mobileno=$PHONE&message=$TXT";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $curl_scraped_page;
?>
```

But I want to insert numbers from a MySQL database column named *Contactnumber*. I've searched but haven't been able to find how to insert MySQL data instead of numbers to which to send messages.

Just to repeat, I want to send SMS to users, using API codes, but all my contact numbers  are save in my database, so I want to insert numbers from the DB into my URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$USERNAME = urlencode ('username');
$PASSWORD = urlencode ('password');
$message = $_POST["msg"];
$TXT = urlencode ($message);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT mobile from students") or die(mysql_error());
while ($mob = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$PHONE.= "$mob[mobile],";
}
$url ="http://bulksms.com:8080/WebSMS/SMSAPI.jsp?username=$USERNAME&password=$PASSWORD&sendername=ONLINE&mobileno=$PHONE&message=$TXT";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $curl_scraped_page;
}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Sujan. Looks like this code could help to answer the question, but it would be better if you could also explain what you're doing to anyone trying to learn how to do this.